# strings.xml: What is ill-formed about this?

Tags: xml, react-native

I basically went to this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/react-native

and copy pasted this:

```
<string name="appCenterCrashes_whenToSendCrashes" moduleConfig="true" translatable="false">DO_NOT_ASK_JAVASCRIPT</string>
<string name="appCenterAnalytics_whenToEnableAnalytics" moduleConfig="true" translatable="false">ALWAYS_SEND</string>
```

and got the error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/danale/Projects/Appcenter/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml:2:2: Error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

Can anyone see what exactly is ill-formed about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A well-formed XML document consists of a single well-formed XML element. Your input contains a sequence of two well-formed XML elements. To make that into a well-formed XML document you need to add a wrapper element.

Comment: your answer is interesting because the above XML elements is exactly how the appcenter docs say to publish them.

Comment: You misread it. It says "Modify the app's res/values/strings.xml to include the following lines:". It doesn't say that it should contain those lines and nothing else.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. I just looked at a working copy and I see its missing the wrapper elements.